# How to get a formatted time without quotation marks?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm trying to return a formatted time but without be as a instance of String.

```
t = Time.now
# => 2016-02-15 21:06:20 -0200 
t.strftime('%T')
# => "21:06:20"
```

How can I get this result without quotation marks?

```
# => 21:06:20
```

Comment: There's no other way to represent it. I believe it has to be a string, and you can parse out the separate HH:MM:SS if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't have quotation marks.  That's just the representation that shows up in IRB.

```
irb(main):001:0> puts Time.now.strftime('%T')
18:14:37
=> nil
```

Comment: Actually if I print with `p t.strftime('%T')` the quotation marks appears, but with `puts t.strftime('%T')` it doesn't. Thank you.

Comment: Because `p` shows the source code representation.  In fact, IRB uses `p` to generate what it shows you.

Comment: Exactly! This helped me.